# Couchbase N1ql - Join between bucket and view

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I need to join between bucket and view in couchbase by n1ql .
It's possible ?

Second , the join query work between **bucket keys** and any attribute and can not work between attribute and attribute (like foreign key) , right ?

Thanks .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, JOINs between a bucket and a map-reduce view are not supported. If you can put the contents of your view into another bucket, you can JOIN between buckets.

Comment: ok , thanks for your replay . more question - the join between buckets - must be between keys from bucketA and attributes in bucketB and no between attr from bucketA and attr in bucketB . right ?

Comment: Correct. That is the limitation for now -- one bucket must contain the key of the other bucket.